# How to change the path of shared memory created using boost library in c++

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I am trying to create a shared memory.
But I am not able to create it in my current project location.Instead the shared memory is created in default location i.e., **/dev/shm**

**Code:**

```
    boost::shared_ptr<bip::managed_shared_memory> segment_Order;
    segment_Order = boost::make_shared<bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::open_or_create, "MyShm", 10 * 1024);
```

**Please suggest me how to change shared memory creation from default location to my configured location.**

Comment: Unclear what you mean with "in my current project location". The whole point of *shared* memory is that the memory is *shared* between processes. Please elaborate what you intend to achieve, and for what reason.

Comment: `/dev/shm/` is where shared memory exists. There is no point in allocating it in the current project location, because that location might not be accessible by other applications, which defeats the purpose of it being shared memory.

Comment: Shared Memory is removed when it is created in /dev/shm after reboot which is something I don't want.

I want to reuse that shared memory after reboot. Thats why I want to change the location from /dev/shm to local direcory.

Comment: Could it be that what you are looking for is not shared memory (which **does**, naturally, not persist across reboots), but a **file** (possibly with additional access synchronization)?

Comment: @HimanshuSharma: **All** memory, shared or not, is gone after a reboot. If you want data to remain after a reboot, it has to go to persistent storage (file, database, etcetera)

Comment: Any solution to this problem? We recently ported our code from Windows to Linux. On Windows, we store the shared memory file in our data folder so we can preserve it. It doesn't look like we can do that on a linux server. Too bad. It takes too long to regenerate the shared memory used for our application.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, `managed_shared_memory` uses [`shm_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html):

> The POSIX shared memory object implementation on Linux makes use of a dedicated `tmpfs(5)` filesystem that is normally mounted under `/dev/shm`.

If you'd like to create a shared memory file in a different location, you may like to use a plain mapped file `managed_mapped_file`. See [Managed Mapped File](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files) for more details.